# Lockify API is not extracting the Data for Whole year

Tags: excel, vba, key, clockify

I've been using the Lockify API for almost two years now. I used to extract data regularly through the API to get real-time insights, and everything was working well. However, recently, I faced an issue where it stopped extracting data for the entire year. I checked the Lockify API, but it seems unchanged, and I couldn't figure out why this problem occurred.

To troubleshoot, I turned to Clockify Reports and exported data from there for comparison. It turns out the issue is in the code, but I'm struggling to identify and fix it. I'm hopeful that someone can assist me in resolving this issue.

Below is the API format which I am using.

```
Dim httpCaller  As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, body As String
Set httpCaller = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

body = "{""dateRangeStart"": ""2023-01-01T00:00:00.000"", " & vbLf & _
       " ""dateRangeEnd"": ""2023-12-31T23:59:59.000"", " & vbLf & _
       " ""detailedFilter"": {""page"": 1,""pageSize"": 1000}} "

' Debug.Print body
httpCaller.Open "POST", "https://reports.api.clockify.me/v1/workspaces/Key/reports/detailed"
httpCaller.setRequestHeader "X-Api-Key", "API_Key"
httpCaller.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
httpCaller.send body
```

Comment: "it stopped extracting data for the entire year" - what did it start doing *instead* of what you expected?

Comment: Hey thank you for replying! I was Extracting the from Jan-2023 to Nov-2023, so it skipped the data for the month of Jan and Feb.

Comment: Do you have more than 1000 results?

Comment: I think Yes! its more than 1000 :( and thats the reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the `detailedFilter` key, you are using static values for the `page` value. This means that it will only ever return the latest 1000 records. You'll need to create a loop to determine how many total records are within your daterange.

There is a field called `entriesCount` in every response which you can calculate off of and loop through the pages iteratively. For example, if the `entriesCount` value is 3250, you'll need to repeat the API call where the `page` value increases iteratively as the values 1,2 then 3.

The reason why older timesheets are not included is that Clockify returns the timesheets newest to oldest so it is returning the 1000 most recent timesheets.

Comment: if its not bother you can you please share an example how to achieve this. I am trying to get the total number of pages based on the entriesCount `totalPages = Application.WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(json("entriesCount") / 1000, 1)` but getting `compile error` on the this line @Adam DS

Comment: Can you confirm that you have parsed the JSON response correctly? I believe the top-level JSON object is named 'totals", then 'entriesCount' is within the 'totals' object.

Comment: I think there is issue with the entry name when i am trying to parse it getting compile error.